# Bug: React component not properly evaluating array length?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux

First post here on SO for me.  Mad respekt to the community!  Apologize for the image links, didn't realize I needed street cred to embed images.

I'm building a toy application using React/Redux and Node and I'm having an issue with a seemingly simple concept.

First image: Nothing crazy here.  I have an array in state that I've appropriate named "arrayInState" and logged to the Chrome console.  On the very next line, I log the length of that array to the console. Here's where it gets weird.  Check out the what Chrome logs in the 2nd photo.

The "arrayInState" clearly has an object at the 0th index and thus a length of 1.  But when I log the length of the array in the FOLLOWING line of code, it reads 0.  Wtf???  Is this a bug?

Thank you in advance!

[My code in VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfTum.png)
[Chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3EQe.png)

Comment: Arrays are stored as object references and as the `i` icon on the console reads, the value was evaluated just as you clicked to expand the array. The array was empty the moment you consoled it, but something was added to it later

Comment: @Agney Ok, that makes sense.  I do make a fetch request when a parent component mounts.  And my understanding is that React re-renders components anytime local state or the PROPS object changes references.  Does this mean that I'm mutating state directly as opposed to overwriting it?

Comment: it might, but that's hard to say without the code

Comment: @Agney That was it.  Lodash is my new bff.  Thank you!